# Gatling test forever using feed

Tags: apache-kafka, gatling

I have a kafka simulation test using Gatling and currently we are able to run with the constantUsersPerSec for a given duration. But we wanted to run this simulation at constantUsersPerSec (say some 1000/sec) and this test should be running forever until somebody kills the test/process.

Currently we have adjusted to use days in place of duration. But is there an option to run a test forever that uses a feeder. Here is the code snippet:

```
val scn = scenario("Kafka Test Demo")
    .feed(ssv(conf.getString("filename"), true).circular)
    .exec(kafka("request")
      // message to send
      .send[String]("${t}"))
  setUp(
    scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(conf.getInt("constantUsersPerSec")) during (conf.getInt("run_duration_in_mins") hours)))
    .protocols(kafkaConf)
```

Any suggestions/directions please?

many thanks,
mpha

Answer (score 0):

Is code bellow going to work?

```
val scn = scenario("Kafka Test Demo")
    .feed(ssv(conf.getString("filename"), true)).circular.forever() {
    exec(kafka("request")
    // message to send
    .send[String]("${t}"))
}
```

Comment: I tried running with the above snippet but it was running the load without posting any messages to topic. Do i need to do any change in the code below since i'm setting duration in the inject, it will not make any sense by telling forever and passing duration:    setUp(
    scn.inject(constantUsersPerSec(conf.getInt("constantUsersPerSec")) during (conf.getInt("run_duration_in_mins") hours)))
    .protocols(kafkaConf)

Comment: Also above code is working but it won't be consistently sending same load of requests, say for example we wanted to send 1000 req/sec then it will be 1000 for a moment and later it can jump randomly to any value which we are uncertain.